# creating files in tizen

Tags: tizen

I am trying to create new file in tizen. My code is

```
var dir;
var newDir = dir.createDirectory("vij");
```

But Its getting Error like

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'dir.createDirectory')
```

I have tried the same example which is given in the Tizen documentation. Please give an idea

Answer (score 4):

Just declare `dir` like so:

```
var dir = tizen.filesystem;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of `var dir;` in your code were you practically declare an undefined `dir` variable you get that error because `dir` will be `undefined`.

If you check the API in Documentation this is the way to do it:

```
 var documentsDir;
 function onsuccess(files) {
   for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
     console.log("File Name is " + files[i].name); // displays file name
   }

   var testFile = documentsDir.createFile("test.txt");
   if (testFile != null) {
     testFile.openStream(
         "w",
         function(fs){
           fs.write("HelloWorld");
           fs.close();
         }, function(e){
           console.log("Error " + e.message);
         }, "UTF-8"
     );
   }
 }

 function onerror(error) {
   console.log("The error " + error.message + " occurred when listing the files in the selected folder");
 }

 tizen.filesystem.resolve(
     'documents',
     function(dir){
       documentsDir = dir; dir.listFiles(onsuccess,onerror);
     }, function(e) {
       console.log("Error" + e.message);
     }, "rw"
 );
```

The two bellow shown examples that you find in the documentation make sense just in the context above were tizen.filesystem.resolve is called.

```
var newDir = dir.createDirectory("newDir");
var anotherNewDir = dir.createDirectory("newDir1/subNewDir1");
```

so if you want to create a file you do the above code (first one entirely) were the file is create in the onsuccess callback of listFiles, if you want to create a directory yo need to do this:

```
tizen.filesystem.resolve(
       'documents', 
       function(dir){
        var newDir = dir.createDirectory("vij");
       }, function(e){
         console.log("Error" + e.message);
       }, "rw"
     );
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need 2 privilages in config.xml to write to files:
`<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.write"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.read"/>`

Can be added manually, or using "previlages" tab.
After that, you shpuld use [Filesystem API methods - createDirectory](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/filesystem.html#createDirectoryidp346592)

`tizen.filesystem.resolve(
    'images',
    function(dir) {
        var dir; //Directory object obtained from filesystem API
        var newDir = dir.createDirectory("newDir");
         console.log("Mount point Name is " +  dir.path);
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e.message);
   }, "rw"
);`

As a result you will have your folder in /opt/usr/media/Images/

Answer (score 2):

this is how you add an file in the tizen web application:

Create a File:

> Creates a empty new file in a specified location that is relative to the directory.
>   "File createFile(DOMString relativeFilePath);"

Example:

```
tizen.filesystem.resolve(
   absolute_path, 
   function(dir){
    dir.createFile(<filename>);
   }, function(e) {
     console.log("Error" + e.message);
   }, "rw"
);
```

More info can be found in this link below:
http://howdoudoittheeasiestway.blogspot.in/2015/02/writing-and-reading-from-file-system.html

Answer (score 2):

You need resolve file or directory object from tizen.filesystem.resolve API befor using directory object.

In your code your dir object is just contain empty string.

So, First get File(file&dir) object from tizen.filesystem.resolve API.

below is tizen.filesystem.resolve api, you can get file object on FileSuccessCallback onsuccess method.

```
void resolve(DOMString location, FileSuccessCallback onsuccess, optional ErrorCallback? onerror, optional FileMode? mode);
```

like below code.

```
tizen.filesystem.resolve(
   'images',
   function(dir) {
     //do something what you want
     console.log("Mount point Name is " +  dir.path);
   }, function(e) {
     console.log("Error: " + e.message);
   }, "r"
 );
```

There is helpfull tutorial and example code on API Reference.

FileSystem Tutorial
https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/tizen-features/base/filesystem#create

Filesystem API Reference
https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/latest/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/filesystem.html

And Below is virtual roots table

```
images - the location for images
videos - the location for videos
music - the location for sounds
documents - the location for documents
downloads - the location for downloaded items
ringtones - the location for ringtones (read-only location)
camera - the location for the pictures and videos taken by a device (supported since Tizen 2.3)
wgt-package - the location for widget package which is read-only
wgt-private - the location for a widget's private storage
wgt-private-tmp - the location for a widget's private volatile storage
```